# Blank page after searching for keywords,productname for products magento 2

Tags: magento2

When I **search product in searchbar** it shows blank page

Find below error

> LAYOUT_frontend_STORE2_46f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles
>   catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.